# React-Redux saga with Typescript: only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-saga

I am trying to use the ILoginWithCorpPassAction like below (ref:banner.tsx) and getting the exception: *'ILoginWithCorpPassAction' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.*

banner.tsx

```
export const BannerContainer = connect(null, { ILoginWithCorpPassAction })(Banner)
```

types.tsx

```
export enum ActionTypes {
        LOGIN_WITH_CORPPASS = 'LOGIN_WITH_CORPPASS'
    }

export interface ILoginWithCorpPassAction {
    type: ActionTypes.LOGIN_WITH_CORPPASS;
}


export type Action = ILoginWithCorpPassAction;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are trying o pass the interface in an object literal `{ ILoginWithCorpPassAction }` but interfaces don't exist at runtime so they  can't be a property of an Object literal. A class could be passed around this way as it is a type but also a runtime object, maybe you want a class instead ? I don't know enough about redux-saga to tell you how to fix it but this is the problem from the TS point of view :)

Comment: You are right, I changed 'ILoginWithCorpPassAction' to a normal function. And it works